# Prove $(A \cup B) \setminus (C \setminus B) = B \cup(A \setminus C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let $A,B,C$ be sets.

I am required to prove the following statement:

$$(A \cup B) \setminus (C \setminus B) = B \cup(A \setminus C)$$

First, I tried to write a **set-wise** proof, but didn't manage to do so. I would like to see such proof.

Second, I tried to prove it **element-wise**. Here's my try:

From the left side, I can write $x \in A\cup B$ and $x \notin C \setminus B$. This splits into $2$ cases:

Case 1: $x \in A \iff x \in A\setminus C \iff x \in B \cup(A \setminus C)$

Case 2: $x \in B  \iff x \in B \cup(A \setminus C)$

Since both cases use only "iff" statements, and both imply that element from one side belongs to the other side as well, then both sides are equal, because it proves both directions needed. But this "proof" completely ignores $x \notin C \setminus B$ so I doubt its validity.

1. So, is my proof correct? Where am I wrong and how do I make use of $x \notin C \setminus B$ (if it's even needed).
2. Can this be proven group-wise?

Comment: Is it so important that $A,B,C$ are groups?

Comment: @kabenyuk I think so. This is the problem description anyways. Maybe "sets" is more appropriate, but I don't have enough knowledge to tell. This question is in the 2nd chapter of the book, so I believe it's not tricky in nature.

Comment: This statement is true for any set. To see it, draw Venn circles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proof:

We have:

$x \in (A \cup B) \setminus (C \setminus B)$

iff $x \in (A \cup B) \land x \notin (C \setminus B)$

Then, $x \notin (C \setminus B)$, iff $\neg (x \in (C \setminus B))$, iff $\neg (x \in C \land x \notin B)$, iff $x \notin C \lor x \in B$.

So: $x \in (A \cup B) \land (x \notin (C \setminus B))$

iff $x \in (A \cup B) \land (x \notin C \lor x \in B)$

iff $[x \in (A \cup B) \land x \notin C] \lor [x \in (A \cup B) \land x \in B]$.

Since we always have $B \subseteq (A \cup B)$, we thus have [$x \in (A \cup B) \land x \in B$] iff $x \in B$.

Also, $[x \in (A \cup B) \land x \notin C]$, iff $[(x \in A \land x \notin C) \lor (x \in B \land x \notin C)]$, iff $[(x \in A \setminus C) \lor (x \in B \setminus C)]$.

Therefore: $[x \in (A \cup B) \land x \notin C] \lor [x \in (A \cup B) \land x \in B]$

iff $(x \in A \setminus C) \lor (x \in B \setminus C) \lor x \in B$

Since we always have $(B \setminus C) \subseteq B$, then we have:

$(x \in A \setminus C) \lor (x \in B \setminus C) \lor x \in B$

iff $(x \in A \setminus C) \lor x \in B$

iff $x \in (A \setminus C) \cup B$

Therefore, $x \in (A \cup B) \setminus (C \setminus B)$ iff $x \in (A \setminus C) \cup B$, and this means $(A \cup B) \setminus (C \setminus B) = (A \setminus C) \cup B$.

Comment: Can you explain why my proof is wrong? What is false in it?

Comment: I think the Case 1 is not true, because $x \in A$ and $x \notin C \setminus B$ does not necessarily imply $x \in A \setminus C$. You see, $x \notin (C \setminus B)$ iff $\neg (x \in (C \setminus B))$ iff $\neg (x \in C \land x \notin B)$ iff $(x \notin C \lor x \in B)$. So it is possible that $x \in B \cap C$, and thus $x \in A$ $\not \Rightarrow$ $x \in A \setminus C$.

Answer (score 2):

**First, an algebraic proof.** Let's write $A^c$ for the complement of $A$.
Then, we have :
\begin{align}
(A\cup B) \backslash (C\backslash B) &= (A\cup B) \backslash (C\cap B^c) \\
&= (A\cup B) \cap (C\cap B^c)^c\\
&= (A\cup B) \cap (C^c \cup B) \\
&=B\cup (A\cap C^c)\\
&= B \cup (A\backslash C)
\end{align}

**Then, about your proof.**

> Case 1: $x \in A \iff x \in A\setminus C \iff x \in B \cup(A \setminus C)$

> Case 2: $x \in B  \iff x \in B \cup(A \setminus C)$

Those equivalences are false.

**A proper element-wise proof**

Let $x \in (A\cup B) \backslash (C\backslash B)$. Then $x \in A \cup B$ and $x\notin C\backslash B$. This last condition is equivalent to $x\in B$ or $x \notin C$.

1. If $x \in B$, then $x\in B\cup (A\backslash C)$.
2. If $x\notin C$ and $x\in A$, then $x\in A\backslash B$ so $x\in B\cup(A\backslash C)$
   This takes care of all cases, so we conclude that $x\in B\cup (A\backslash C)$.

Conversely, let $x \in B\cup (A\backslash C)$.

1. If $x \in B$, then $x \in A\cup B$ and $x\notin C\backslash B$. Therefore $x \in (A\cup B)\backslash (C\backslash B)$.
2. If $x\in (A\backslash C)$, then $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$. Therefore, $x\in A\cup B$ and $x \notin C\backslash A$, so $x\in (A\cup B)\backslash (C\backslash B)$
   We conclude that in every cases, $x\in (A\cup B)\backslash (C\backslash B)$.

This being true for any element $x$, we have :
$$(A\cup B)\backslash (C\backslash B) = B\cup(A\backslash C)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for proving this in every way possible!!! Can you please elaborate why my equivalences are wrong? Don't they imply each-other? I don't understand. Because for example, if $x$ is in $A$, it is also in $A \setminus C$, and also in $B \cup(A \setminus C)$. I don't understand why it's wrong.

Comment: If $x$ belongs to $A$, it can be in $A\backslash C$ or in $A\cap C$. The two are possible and exclusive. Thus, $x\in A \not\Rightarrow x\in A \backslash C$.